# PHP: Finding array index number?

Tags: php, arrays, search

For anyone that really wants a challenge! :)

How would I go about finding the index of `eirepanel_inline_ads_options_name` using a string such as `Wonder Bingo = 0`

```
array(4) {
  ["eirepanel_inline_ads_options_saved"]=>
  string(4) "true"
  ["eirepanel_inline_ads_options_name"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "Wonder Bingo"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "City Bingo"
  }
  ["eirepanel_inline_ads_options_affiliate_link"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(20) "/visit/wonder_bingo/"
    [1]=>
    string(17) "/visit/city_bingo"
  }
  ["eirepanel_inline_ads_options_thumbnail"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(45) "http://www.freenodepositbingo.co.uk/image.png"
    [1]=>
    string(46) "http://www.freenodepositbingo.co.uk/image2.png"
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `Wonder Bingo = 0` mean? The string `"Wonder Bingo"` should be at the `0` index of the value of the key you search for? Also, have you already tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace('/ = \d+$/', '', 'Wonder Bingo = 0');

$key = array_search($str, $array['eirepanel_inline_ads_options_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, just figured it out.

```
echo $key = array_search('WonderBingo', $eirepanel_inline_ads_options['eirepanel_inline_ads_options_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting requirements as `Wonder Bingo = 0` meaning *the `0` index of the searched for key equals `"Wonder Bingo"`*:

```
function find($needle, $haystack) {
    preg_match('/^(.+) = (\d+)$/', $needle, $matches);
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($value[$matches[2]]) && $value[$matches[2]] == $matches[1]) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
}
```